# Firefox 52.6: Can I filter out messages about sites I do not want?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, console

I found earlier iterations of this issue in Stackoverflow, but old enough that the info might not be current

---

I am trying to develop and debug Javascript in a site I am working on.

When I have the Firefox Browser Console up, with the JS tab clicked I get all sorts of irrelevant messages from other sites I have loaded in other tabs and need open.

Is there any way I can tell the Browser Console to only send me messages about the site I am working on?

Comment: How are you bringing up the Browser Console? F12, Ctrl+Shift+K, or Ctrl+Shift+J? Nevermind ... Don't use "Browser Console" (Ctrl+Shift+J), use "Web Console" (Ctrl+Shift+K)

Comment: Web Console seems to be avoiding the garbage messages.  Is it possible to set it up to come out automatically upon detecting a javascript error?

Comment: Not sure, Have you checked the options in developer tools console?